# Why are my HTML templates disappearing in flex builder when I target fp10?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flexbuilder, flashplayer-10

When I target flash player 10 in flex builder 3, the index.html template along with some other files (history.js, etc) are removed and no wrapper html page is built.

Anyone else experiencing this? I have an ant build script as well, but I was trying to run the built in fb builder.

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning you project then build the whole project again. Im using ecplise in building my flex project do i cant tell you how to clean the project in flex builder.. hope this idea helps.

Comment: Nope, cleaning isnt the issue. It actually removes the .html file from html-templates directory when I target 10. If I put it back to 9 it adds them back. It might be looking for the template files inside the sdk folder? Im not sure about that though.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your project's properties (right click, Properties)
2. Go to Flex Compiler
3. Under "Html wrapper" uncheck "Generate HTML wrapper file"
4. Click "Apply"
5. Then check "Generate HTML wrapper file" (the same one you just unchecked)
6. Click "Apply"

You should now see that the html wrapper files are regenerated.